Opening App Shortcut On Android Does Not Call The onResume() Function Of The Main Activity
I'm trying to create a shortcut for my android app that calls some code when it is opened. I have followed the Official Guide to create the shortcut, and it shows up correctly on my smartphone:
Screenshot of the shortcut.
However, I use some code in the onResume function of my MainActivity to call some code whenever the shortcut is used. The problem is that onResume is not getting called when opening the app through the shortcut. When I open the app normally by pressing on it's icon, the onResume function is called.
Are there any configuration options I have to make so that the shortcut "resumes" my main activity?
Important part of AndroidManifest.xml:
<!-- Between the application tag -->
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:exported="true"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>

  <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
    android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
</activity>

res/xml/shortcuts.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <shortcut
    android:shortcutId="play_favourites"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/heart_outline"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/play_favourites_short_label">
  
    <intent
      android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
      android:targetPackage="ch.silvanschmidt.fimusic"
      android:targetClass="ch.silvanschmidt.fimusic.MainActivity" />
  </shortcut>
</shortcuts>

I'm expecting the onResume function to run when I open the application using a shortcut. However, it only resumes when I use the normal icon launcher.

You screenshot of a "Shortcut" looks like a full-on Activity. Is that correct? Maybe clarify and expand what "called when opening the app through the shortcut" means. What exact steps are you taking and what exactly is happening.

Yes, that is correct (Is the "Play Favourites" button in the screenshot not a shortcut?). I'm adding a feature to a music player to instantly start playing a playlist using a shortcut. To achieve this I later want to add an extra to the shortcut (or use a custom action, not the android.intent.action.VIEW one) and check for that in the onResume function and start playing that playlist when activating the shortcut.
